# Using enum and switch case combination in Swift

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

Here is my code:

```
enum GameScreen
{
    case kSceneFlashScreen
    case kSceneMainMenu
    case kSceneGameScreen
    case kSceneStoreScreen
    case kSceneGameOver
}

class YSGameManager: NSObject {

    func replaceGameScene(inScreen: GameScreen)
    {
        switch inScreen
        {
            case GameScreen.kSceneGameScreen: //Error for here
            case GameScreen.kSceneMainMenu : //here also error


        }
    }
}
```

Eror LOG: **'case' label in a 'switch' should have at least one executable statement**

How to use enum in switch case in Swift ?

Comment: Did you have a look at the "related questions "?

Comment: @MartinR, sorry I thought its new error in Xcode 6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an error because you haven't got anything after `:` and before the next `case`. To solve this you can:

**1.** Add some code to do something.

**2.** Add `fallthrough` if you want to move to the next `case`. This may have been what you were trying to do. However, in Swift, `switch` statements don't fallthrough by default to the next case, they `break`.

**3.** Add `break` to stop the `switch` statement.

Comment: This helped me a lot, the alternative is the ugly if statement, i hate if statements 

Answer (score 2):

It’s complaining that you need to actually do something after the matching `case`.  Otherwise there’s not much point matching it, and chances are it’s a typo.

Other possibly than coverage i.e. if you don’t want a `default`, you want to name every possible enum, even though you don’t want to do anything for some of them.  In which case, stick in a `break`:

```
switch inScreen {
case kSceneGameScreen:
    break
// etc.
}
```

Note, there’s no implicit fall through in Swift’s switch statements. You need to give one explicitly:

```
switch inScreen {
case kSceneGameScreen:
    // do a game-screen-specific thing
    fallthrough   // then
case kSceneMainMenu:
    // do a thing for both
    // kSceneGameScreen and kSceneMainMenu
// etc.
}
```

But if you just want to match two possibilities, you don’t need to use fall through, you can just combine them with `,`:

```
switch inScreen {
case kSceneGameScreen, kSceneMainMenu:
    // do a thing for both
    // kSceneGameScreen and kSceneMainMenu
// etc.
}
```